# Sparsifiers for 3-term arithmetic progressions

Tags: co.combinatorics, additive-combinatorics

Let $G$ be a finite abelian group of odd order, let $D\subseteq G$, and $\epsilon \in (0,1)$.
For $S\subseteq G$ define
$$
\Lambda(S) = \frac{1}{|S||G|} \sum_{s\in S}\sum_{g\in G} 1_S(s)1_S(s+g)1_S(s+2g)
$$
(i.e., a normalized count of the number of 3-term APs in $S$)
and define
$$
\Lambda_D(S) = \frac{1}{|S||D|} \sum_{s\in S}\sum_{d\in D} 1_S(s)1_S(s+d)1_S(s+2d),
$$
(i.e., a normalized count of the number of 3-term APs in $S$ whose common difference lies in $D$).

Suppose that
$
|\Lambda(S) - \Lambda_D(S)| \leq \epsilon
$
holds for every set $S\subseteq G$.
How large must $|D|$ be?
The Cayley graph Cay$(G, \{d, 2d: d\in D\})$ has expansion properties that imply $|D| \geq c\log |G|$ for some $c = c(\epsilon)>0$.
Does a significantly stronger bound in fact hold true?